# Register.php redirected to a blank page

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a registration page in PHP with MYSQL . My index.php page has a form which I have to fill in , and upon registration , it is supposed to show the status of registration , whether it is successful or not , and whether confirmation link is being sent to the email. However , when I click register , it redirects to register.php where nothings is being shown - all i see is a blank page no matter what info i key in. Furthermore , upon checking my table (user) in database (users) , I realized that no data is being input. My database connection is correct since I have verified it and i suspect that the error is in register.php . can anyone take a look at it and guide me on what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

my index.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sign Up</title>
<style>
 label{
  width:100px;
  float:left;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
 session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
 {
  echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['username'].'</p>';
  echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['email'].'</p>';
  echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['password'].'</p>';
  echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['mail_add'].'</p>';
  unset($_SESSION['error']);
 }
?>
<div class="signup_form">
<form action="register.php" method="post" >
 <p>
  <label for="username">User Name:</label>
  <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="30"/>
 </p>
 <p>
  <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
  <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30"/>
 </p>
 <p>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="30 "/>
 </p>
 <p>
  <label for="mail_add">Mailing:</label>
  <input name="mail_add" type="text" id="mail_add" size="30"/>
 </p>
 <p>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </p>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My register.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('configdb.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 //whether the username is blank
 if($_POST['username'] == '')
 {
  $_SESSION['error']['username'] = "User Name is required.";
 }
  if($_POST['mail_add'] == '')
 {
  $_SESSION['error']['mail_add'] = "Mailing address is required.";
 }
 //whether the email is blank
 if($_POST['email'] == '')
 {
  $_SESSION['error']['email'] = "E-mail is required.";
 }
 else
 {
  //whether the email format is correct
  if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email']))
  {
   //if it has the correct format whether the email has already exist
   $email= $_POST['email'];
   $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$email'";
   $result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql1) or die(mysqli_error());
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0)
            {
    $_SESSION['error']['email'] = "This Email is already used.";
   }
  }
  else
  {
   //this error will set if the email format is not correct
   $_SESSION['error']['email'] = "Your email is not valid.";
  }
 }
 //whether the password is blank
 if($_POST['password'] == '')
 {
  $_SESSION['error']['password'] = "Password is required.";
 }

  //if the error exist, we will go to registration form
 if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
 {
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit;
 }
 else
 {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $mail_add = $_POST['mail_add'];
  $com_code = md5(uniqid(rand()));

  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO user (username, email, password, com_code , mail_add) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password', '$com_code', '$mail_add')";
  $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error());

  if($result2)
  {
   $to = $email;
   $subject = "Confirmation from TutsforWeb to $username";
   $header = "TutsforWeb: Confirmation from TutsforWeb";
   $message = "Please click the link below to verify and activate your account. rn";
   $message .= "http://www.yourname.com/confirm.php?passkey=$com_code";

   $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

   echo "Records finally inserted into table.";

   if($sentmail)
            {
   echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
   }
   else
         {
    echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
   }
  }
  else {
      echo "Cannot insert into table";
  }
 }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: I added it on top of register.php and it gives me this :

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\Users\nyan\Desktop\BFS\EmptySite9\register.php on line 63

Comment: ANd what is the line 63 on your code?

Comment: Do `mysqli_error($mysqli)` - change all `or die(mysqli_error());` to `or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));`

Comment: Line 63 -  $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error());

Comment: Also, the header you're using `$header = "TutsforWeb: Confirmation from TutsforWeb";` could be invalid. I suggest you read the manual on `mail()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: As the docs states on [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) you have to pass the connection as a parameter.

Comment: Try giving it one then. (id) - I noticed you deleted your comment about it not having a default value.

Comment: Guys , i have tried the mysqli)error($mysqli) and now it is giving me - "Field 'id' does not have a default value." I'll read up on the mail() manual and alter it accordingly. at the mean time , can you tell me what's the meaning of the above stated error about the id? sorry guys , i'm still learning php from scratch.

Comment: Do you have a column called `id` in your DB?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes I do , and i followed : 


CREATE TABLE `user` (
`id` INT( 50 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`username` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`email` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`password` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`com_code` VARCHAR( 255 ) default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
) ENGINE = InnoDB

To create the table in my DB.

Comment: Alright guys , I have tried running the command : 

ALTER TABLE auth_user MODIFY `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 

and the error seemed to have gone away. now it shows



Notice: Undefined variable: header in C:\Users\nyan\Desktop\BFS\EmptySite9\register.php on line 72

Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in C:\Users\nyan\Desktop\BFS\EmptySite9\register.php on line 72
Records finally inserted into table.Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address


but i will read the manual and solve it. thanks alot Fred and Jorge for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Enjoy your code